# PostDeployment and PreDeployment scripts do not successfully execute sp_grantdbaccess or CREATE USER statements in my DB project. Why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to create a user for a specific login using pre and post-deployment scripts in my db project. I am using SQL Server 2008 R2, VS 2012, and patience. Each time I publish all other commands in the scripts seem to execute but not the CREATE USER line; nor does an alternative call to sp_grantdbaccess.

Answer (score 0):

Can you maybe post the generated code ? I normally create the users within the db context, not using pre or post scripts for that, since the user is a normal object within the database (Add new item, under security you get code created:

```
CREATE USER [User1]
    WITHOUT LOGIN
    WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo

GO

GRANT CONNECT TO [User1]
```